# C++: disallowing virtual function in derived class at compile vs runtime

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a parent `class RO` that has a method `void setup(const int* p)`. I need a child `class RW` to have same method that allows non-const pointers only.

I do it by creating two methods in `class RO` and disallowing one of them in `class RW`:

```
class RO
{
public:
    void setup(int* p) { DO SMTH }
    virtual void setup (const int* p) { RO::setup( const_cast<int*>(p) ); }

    // the rest...
    void read() const;
};

class RW : public RO
{
public:
    virtual void setup (const int* p) { throw SMTH }

    // the rest...
    void write();
};
```

I'd like to be able to disallow `RW::setup` at compile time when possible. I.e.,

```
const int* p;

RO* ro = new RW;
ro->setup(p);        // Throw at run time, since it can be unknown
                     // at compile time that ro points to RW and not to RO.

RW* rw = new RW;
rw->f(p);            // Disallow this at compile time, since it is
                     // known at compile time that rw points to RW.
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Public inheritance may not be the right model for your problem, since clearly `B` *is not* an `A`.

Comment: If anything, your inheritance is backwards and `A` is a subclass of `B`

Comment: You can declare the method `f` in `B` private. Then it is not possible to call it on a `B` object. However, you have also make the other function `f` visible in `B` due to name hiding.

Comment: Well, my example is simplified. `A` is kind of a "read-only" class that only allows "get" methods. `B` is "read-write" class that allows both "get" and "set" methods. So it is convenient to inherit `B` from `A`.

Comment: Why would read/write class choose not to inherit a method from a read only class?

Comment: If so, RW class can take pointer to const data, and write operations can damage that data. RW class should take pointers to non-const data only, whereas RO class never changes anything so it is ok to pass it pointer to const as well as to non-const.

Comment: I wonder what that `A` and `B` is you guys are talking about, since the OP only mentioned `RO` and `RW`.

Comment: You don't need to disallow anything in class RW. Let it have both methods. Absolutely nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use private instead of public inheritance. Make methods of the parent class available in the child class using the `using` keyword.

Public inheritance is meant for situations where someone who uses a parent class object might as well use a chid class object (look up [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) for details). Your requirement breaks that, so it's no case for public inheritance.

Comment: @NateKohl: Did you mean to say "composition"?

Comment: @EdS. ugh, yes.  Yes I did.

Comment: Composition is also an option. And I sill find the concept of private ineritance strange (it's a composition with syntactic suger, after all).

Comment: I think you mean the `using` keyword. don't you?

Comment: @Fred Yep, too much PHP lately

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `class RO` has an invariant: "Never modifies `*p`" (even though it does a sneaky `const_cast` on `p`).  If `class RW` violates that invariant, it CANNOT be a subclass of `class RO`.

I'm guessing what you really want is something more like:

```
class Readable {
public:
    virtual ~Readable();
    virtual void read() const = 0;
};

class RO
  : public Readable {
public:
    void setup(const int* p);
    void read() const;
private:
    const int* m_p;
};

class RW
  : public Readable
{
public:
    void setup(int* p);
    void read() const;
    void write();
private:
    int* m_p;
};
```

And if the followup question is: "What about DRY? Now I have to implement `read()` twice?", note that you can define a static member function in base class `Readable` something like:

```
    static void do_read(const int* p);
```